# Is there any way of removing the "title" field from a list in Sharepoint 2003?

Tags: sharepoint

I cannot find a way of removing the 'Title' field from the a new list in Sharepoint 2003. I see that I can rename it, but I dont want a "single line of text" field at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the 'Title' field.  You may rename it or hide it, but that is all.